# Visual Studio 2017 installer does nothing after extracting files

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Any time I run the installer for [Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/), it shows a brief "Extracting Files" screen, then silently closes without any error message.

[image: Animated gif of Visual Studio failing to install]

Looking at task manager, when `vs_Community.exe` finishes extracting files, it launches another process called `vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe`. Both processes are only active for about two seconds and do not persist after the installer has closed.

[image: Task manager - 'vs_Community.exe' and 'vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe']

I am using a Lenovo laptop running Windows 7 Professional SP1 (x86). While it's a fairly old computer, it should meet Visual Studio's [minimum system requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs).

Comment: Have you tried to run the installer as an Administrator?  If this is a machine connected to an active domain you have been asking about, there is a good chance, there is a group policy that is preventing the installation Visual Studio.  Have you asked your Administrator for assistance?

Comment: @Ramhound You are correct in assuming this is a work machine connected to an active domain. I hadn't considered that group policy could be the cause.

Comment: Did you ever determine anything with this or get a solution? If so, I think it'd be worth writing an answer if you've gotten one or more specific detail how to resolve, etc. as I noticed a post that was closed referencing this post with no answer. Tag me back if you have any new news with this issue.

Comment: @Facebook I have not made any progress on this issue. I'm inclined to believe [Ramhound's suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/1242301/visual-studio-2017-installer-does-nothing-after-extracting-files?noredirect=1#comment1821403_1242301) that the issue may be caused group policy restrictions.